# Can I upgrade from IE8 to IE9 only? Not go as far as 10 or 11

Tags: internet-explorer, upgrade, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm currently testing an application in IE8, I want to upgrade to IE9 but when I got to the Windows website, it will only let me upgrade straight to IE11, I can't find any option to only go as far as IE9.

Here's the link:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie-9-worldwide-languages

Obviously Windows don't want you using their older software when better options are available, but for testing purposes I really need IE9.

Would anyone have any advice or suggestions? Is my best bet just to upgrade to 11 and uninstall updates to get back to 9? Which is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043971/how-to-downgrade-from-internet-explorer-11-to-internet-explorer-10).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Internet Explorer 9

The standalone installer is available in the [Microsoft Download Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-9-details.aspx). The website will *still* recommend a newer version, but you can actually choose IE 9 if you want to.

In case you need it for testing purposes only, consider using the [free virtual machines provided by Microsoft](http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads). This way you can test you application in multiple versions at the same time, and without having to upgrade/downgrade the browser in your main system.

Comment: +1 for the virtual machine option. The stand alone installer is no longer available unless you are on Vista or Server 2008. They force you into IE11 otherwise.

Comment: This page http://techdows.com/2011/03/download-ie9-final-offlinestandalone-installer.html has direct links to Windows 7 IE9, currently http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/1/6/C167B427-722E-4665-9A40-A37BC5222B0A/IE9-Windows7-x64-enu.exe . The installer still downloads additional components but worked for me on Windows 7 SP1. The Vista IE9 installer available from MS appears to start in on Windows 7 SP1 in Vista SP2 compatibility mode but complains about needing an upgrade. Perhaps with the right Windows updates installed it would work too.

Answer (score 0):

IE 9 Download http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/internet-explorer-9-details.aspx

This setup will work only on windows 7.

Windows 8 have default IE 10 (not upgradable)and Windows 8.1 have IE 11 by Default